# Why curve has Jordan measure equal $0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, curves

There is a theorem that curve $y=f(x)$, where $f:\ [a;b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is a continuous function on this interval, then it's Jordan measure is equal $0$. Why is this so?

I have been taught that Jordan measure is an extension of the notion of size (length, area, volume), so shouldn't the Jordan measure of a curve be it's length? So it should be non-zero for $a\neq b$.

Comment: The same reason that even if a line has positive length, it has zero **area**

Comment: @CalvinKhor ok, that I understand,  but why do we calculate area, and not the length?

Comment: @CalvinKhor is that because that curve is in 2D, so we use Jordan measure for 2D structures?

Comment: You are free to do either. But it takes some effort to calculate the length. If you have a smooth enough curve you can do it classically with differential geometry. Otherwise I believe but am not sure that you should be looking into Hausdorff measure. The precise statement of the theorem must be for 2D measure, treating the graph of the function as a subset of $[a,b]\times \mathbb R$, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that the author means the [Peano-Jordan measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure) of the graph of $f$ in $[a,b]\times \Bbb R\subseteq \Bbb R^2$.

The graph of a function cannot contain a polyrectangle and therefore its inner Peano-Jordan measure is $0$. This means that if the graph is Peano-Jordan measurable then its measure is $0$.

To see that, in your case, $m^*(\operatorname{gr} f)=0$ as well, notice that $f:[a, b]\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and therefore uniformly continuous. Therefore, for every $\varepsilon$ there is some $\delta_\varepsilon<1$ such that $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert<\varepsilon$ for all $x,y$ such that $\lvert x-y\rvert\le\delta_\varepsilon$. This implies that for all $x\in [a,b]$, $$\left(\left(x-\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}2,x+\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}2\right]\times\Bbb R\right)\cap\operatorname{gr}f\subseteq \left(x-\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}2,x+\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}2\right]\times\left(f(x)-\varepsilon,f(x)+\varepsilon\right]$$

Therefore, for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can select $a=x_0<x_1<\cdots< x_N\le b$ such that $x_n-x_{n-1}=\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}3$ and $b-x_N<\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}3$, and consider the cover $$\operatorname{gr}f\subseteq \bigcup_{j=0}^N \left(x_j-\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}2,x_j+\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}2\right]\times\left(f(x_j)-\varepsilon,f(x_j)+\varepsilon\right]$$

This means that $$m^*(\operatorname{gr}f)\le m^*\left(\bigcup_{j=0}^N \left(x_j-\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}2,x_j+\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}2\right]\times\left(f(x_j)-\varepsilon,f(x_j)+\varepsilon\right]\right)\le \\\le\sum_{j=0}^Nm^*\left(\left(x_j-\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}2,x_j+\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}2\right]\times\left(f(x_j)-\varepsilon,f(x_j)+\varepsilon\right]\right)=2(N+1)\varepsilon\delta_\varepsilon$$

Notice, in addition to that, that by construction $N$ is a very specific number: $$N=\left\lfloor \frac{b-a}{\frac{\delta_\varepsilon}3} \right\rfloor\le 3\frac{b-a}{\delta_\varepsilon}$$

therefore, $$m^*(\operatorname{gr}f)\le (6(b-a)+2\delta_\varepsilon)\varepsilon\le (6(b-a)+2)\varepsilon$$

Taking the $\inf$ over $\varepsilon>0$, we obtain $m^*(\operatorname{gr}f)=0$.